# Are only symmetric matrices orthogonally diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Can't we create an orthogonal basis for a matrix A as long as A is diagonalizable? Does A have to be symmetric for it to be orthogonally diagonalizable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that we are working with real matrices, and we  can write $A=U^TDU$

Then $A^T=U^TD^T(U^T)^T=U^TDU=A$

Comment: shouldn't $A^T = UDU^T$?

Comment: if $A=BC$, $A^T=C^TB^T$.